# How to connect to a MySQL Data Source in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, datasource, mysql-connector

I use the [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)  to connect to my database by referencing the assembly (MySql.Data.dll) and passing in a connection string to `MySqlConnection`.  I like that because I don't have to install anything.

**Is there some way to "Choose Data Source" in Visual Studio 2010 without installing something?**

*How can I get a MySQL option (localhost) to show up on one of these lists?  Or do I have to install something?*

(I don't want to use ODBC btw)

**"Add Connection" from Server Explorer:**
[image]

**Entity Data Model Wizard:**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio requires that DDEX Providers (Data Designer Extensibility) be registered by adding certain entries in the Windows Registry during installation (`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version}\DataProviders`) . See [DDEX Provider Registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb163935.aspx) in MSDN for more details.

Answer (score 35):

install the MySQL .NET Connector found here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am familiar with the link to that driver!

Comment: @JohnB then what's the problem? f00's screenshot shows that MySql appears as an option in the "Choose Data Source" dialog.

Comment: @Lucas, no I get that, my question was whether is was possible to Add a Connection through the Server Explorer by just using the `MySql.Data.dll` assembly.  @f00: +1 for your help.

Comment: @JohnB Oops, I misread, though you meant it didn't show up for you. I'll add an answer with details, for future reference :) and +1 f00

Comment: See my post below - it seems you may need to install older drivers for VS2010!!

Comment: I did the same, along with the standalone installer for VS (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/), restart Visual Studio 2017 and there were the driver ready to use. It did not appear on VS2019, though.

Answer (score 27):

"Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio available using the MySQL Installer for Windows."

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.6.html

Answer (score 15):

After a lot of searching and trying many solutions, I got it finally:

1. uninstall connector
2. uninstall MySQL for Visual Studio from control panel

   [image: click here]
3. reinstall them according to the table below

   [image: click here]
4. copy the assembly files from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8\Assemblies\v4.5` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE`
5. log off and reopen your solution
6. enjoy

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a common problem. I had to uninstall the latest Connector/NET driver (6.7.4) and install an older version (6.6.5) for it to work. Others report 6.6.6 working for them.

See other topic with more info: [MySQL Data Source not appearing in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774997/1414258)

Comment: Had a similar experience. MySQL wouldn't show in the Data Sources list using Connector/NET 6.7.4. Version 6.6.5 was fine though.

Comment: THANK YOU MKATAJA AND SERGIO!!!!!!! Uninstalling my current MySQL Connector from Control Panel, installing 6.6.6, relaunching VS worked perfectly! Thank you!!

Comment: Starting version 6.7, Visual Studio integration was splitted into a different product, MySql for Visual Studio, see http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: Thanks!  I installed the most recent version of SqlConnector and it didn't work for VS2010.  Installed 6.6.6, and success!

Answer (score 8):

1. Download MySQL Connector .NET (6.9.4 on this date) from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/#downloads) and install it **CUSTOM**!
2. Remove the ASP.NET WEB providers option or the installer will write in machine.config!
3. Download MySQL for Visual Studio from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/) and install it **CUSTOM**. Be sure to check the integration options. You need this step because after Connector .NET 6.7 the installer will no longer integrate the connector with Visual Studio. This installer can take longer then expected. This is it.

You can install it from alternate download [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html) which should have integrated with VS correctly but it did not and I got a strange error and after the reinstall it is ok.

Comment: Confirming this to work for Visual Studio 2015 aswell!

Comment: You're my hero!

Comment: Work for Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 4):

Installing the following packages:

- Connector/NET 8.0.16: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

adds **MySQL Database** to the data sources list (Visual Studio 2017)

Comment: I was missing the second installer for VS2019: "MySQL for Visual Studio".

Answer (score 2):

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLAia.png)I have got the same problem for my vs 2013 on 64-bit machine. So i tried to download [MySql extension for VS](https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1.msi) and install it on my machine. and restart the vs.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the **MySQL Database** item in the **Choose Data Source** window, one should install the **MySQL for Visual Studio** package available here (the last version today is **1.2.6**):

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: hi friend i installed 1.2.7 which is compatible with visual studio 2017

Comment: Clicking the arrow up would be the best praise.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click the Project in Solution Explorer and click Manage NuGet Packages

Search for MySql.Data package, when you find it click on Install

Here is the sample controller which connects to MySql database using the mysql package. We mainly make use of MySqlConnection connection object.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<employeemodel> employees = new List<employeemodel>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "SELECT EmployeeId, Name, Country FROM Employees";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
               con.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        employees.Add(new EmployeeModel
                        {
                            EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["EmployeeId"]),
                            Name = sdr["Name"].ToString(),
                            Country = sdr["Country"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return View(employees);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by uninstalling MySQL Connector for visualstudio and Mysql for visualstudio, (since I used version 2022 of visual studio I had to download version 2017, 2019 also supports it) and reinstalling the previous components and using a framework version for mysql (it is a bit annoying since sqlserver is simpler)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this is not supported in the builtin tools in visual studio. however, you can create your own data provider using mysql connector but still have to integrate it from code

Comment: Any examples on how to use my own data provider to create ASP.NET Reports? All the examples I have seen use the built in wizards/tools.

Answer (score 0):

a) Visual Studio 2019 (connector for version 2022 does not exists)!

b) [MySQL Installer Community](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/installer/) 8.0.28 (not later)!

b) Clean installation - some configuration data stays from previous version (Program Files, Program Data, AppData, Registry, ...), and installer use it, so MySQL service sometimes freezes during installation.

c) MySQL 5 compatibility mode! No SHA caching option more!

No problems with login.
Tables are visible in VS connection guide.
No utf8mb3 | .NET Framework problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).