# Mysql Datasource is absent in datasource in data connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, winforms

I installed MySQL server in my desktop, but MySQL is absent from the datasource list in dataconnections.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I need

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to a MySQL Data Source in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235291/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install MySql [Connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) API.

EDIT:

[How to connect to a MySQL Data Source in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235291/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio)