# MySQL Data Source not appearing in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

I just installed the ADO.NET connector from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Yet MySQL doesn't appear as a data source like it should. I tried restarting Visual Studio. It doesn't fix my issue. Did I install the wrong connector?

[image]

EDIT: STill nothing. I'm using Visual Studio Express For Desktop. Do I need to pay for the Ultimate edition to use a MySQL Data Source?

Comment: Check out my answer here for VS2013: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20589057/1002222

Comment: I have the same issue for VS2013 but it is appearing well in VS2012...

Comment: As stated in release notes, MySql Visual Studio integration has never been supported in Visual Studio Express editions.

Comment: Install an archive 6.9.5, 32 bit, from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/.

Comment: In visual studio 2022 doesn't work

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was having the same problem just now. I solved it by uninstalling the latest Connector/NET drivers (6.7.4) and then installed the older drivers (6.6.5) and it works.

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I uninstalled the latest ones because I figured they were somehow related to .NET4.5, which I'm not able to use.

---

**Update #1:**

Supposedly another way is to register the MySql Connector with various Visual Studio versions (2010/2012/2013/2015...) during installation: Go to **Modify Product Features** and select all the relevant Visual Studio versions.

[image: see Image]

---

**Update #2 - Visual Studio 2019 Update:**

When I installed MySQL Community with the *ConnectorNET* and *VisualStudio Plugin* options included - MySQL didn't show up as a data provider in Visual Studio.

The installer I used included the VS Plugin version 1.2.9, which had supposedly fixed installation issues from 1.2.8, but still didn't work for me...

**The solution** for me was to uninstall the Connector and the Visual Studio Plugin, download them as individual components, and then install them separately (not as part of the MySQLServer Installer). Install the Connector first, then VS plugin after.

- [Connector Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
- [VS Plugin Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html)

I found the solution [here](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,673879,673989#msg-673989), Thanks to @LambertHeenan.

---

**NOTE about Visual Studio Express**

The OP asks whether MySQL is supported with *Visual Studio Express* (which as far as I can tell has [been renamed to Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/express/)). In the past MySQL officially didn't support Visual Studio Express, as per @Paul's answer below, but they do officially support Visual Studio Community 2017 and 2019, according to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html).

Comment: Worked for me using VS 2010 Ultimate. Downloaded from [link](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/mysql/Downloads/Connector-Net/)

Comment: yes also had troubles with 6.7.4, 6.6.6 worked for me. 
 - i also find it important to point out that it might not work with vs2010 express - version

Comment: Starting Connector/Net 6.7, Visual Studio support was splitted into this product, http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/ (you need to install both Cnet 6.7+ & MySql for Visual Studio for latest features).

Comment: its 2k17 but still this works. latest version didnt work for me

Comment: I opened the same screenshot in this answer but since i had installed MySql before having installed VS 2017 it wasn't listed there. The solution was to up

Comment: can anyone tell me which version is used for Vs 2015 ?

Comment: Exact Solution!
I tried many times re-installing from MySQL Installer but issue remained same.
But then saw your answer, downloaded & installed separately and now it is working!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the same problem but in this case with VS2022, MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5 is the only one supported but when it try to install it over W10, the wizard "closed repently". Any work arrond, pls?

Comment: @DavidCon I also had the same issue. Has anybody found any solution yet?

Comment: @Matin I personally prefer to use MariaDB (drop in replacement of MySQL) with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql nuget package instead of using MySQL EF.

Answer (score 15):

Stuzor and hexcodes solution worked for me as well. However, if you do want the latest connector you have to download another  product. From the oracle website:

Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio available using the MySQL Installer for Windows (see http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html).

Comment: Be warned that the MySql Installer has some issues.  There is a version that will download the sources for you - that would not work for me.  Kept 404'ing on the download.  I had to download the complete 190MB installer to get the Visual Studio tools installed (they are under the "Applications" section, not "Connector").

Comment: The standalone installer for MySql for Visual Studio is available here, http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Answer (score 14):

I found this on the MySQL support page for the Visual Studio connectors.

It appears that they do not support the MySQL to Visual Studio EXPRESS editions.

So to answer your question, yes you may need the ultimate version or professional edition - just not Express to be able to use MySQL with VS.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,546265,564533#msg-564533[image]

Comment: Alas, this is true - but! Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, also free, does support MySQL connections, using this: http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-for-VisualStudio/mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.3.msi.  Thanks to https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/you_can_use_mysql_for.

Answer (score 12):

From [the MySql site.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio available using the MySQL Installer for Windows (see http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html).

Comment: This sounded like a good lead, but did not solve the problem. No mySQL options appear.

Answer (score 9):

Tried everything but on Visual Studio 2015 Community edition I got it working when I installed MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.4+ from
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/
At time of writing I could download 1.2.6 which worked for me.

[image]

Release notes of 1.2.4 which adds support for VS2015 can be found at http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,633391

Comment: Mine refused , i did all that what is the possiblity of the problem am using VS2015

Comment: Wat was refused, be more precise.

Comment: Mysql Databse is still not visible in my Visual Studio 2015 , i tried all what you said , i read several forums but still it has refused , **Is there any manual way of making it work**

Comment: Wow..! Your solution worked like a charm for VS2012. GBU. thanks

Comment: same for me for `Visual Studio Enterprise 2019`: needed to install `MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.10+`; you can find it at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Answer (score 2):

The Connector 6.7.x does not integrate the native data provider anymore. For "Visual Studio 2012" or less, you have to install "MySQL for Visual Studio".
If you are using "Visual Studio 2013" there is no possibility to integrate MySQL for the "Entity Framework" yet.
A solution should be available on 10/2013!

Comment: MySQL for Visual Studio is supposed to be out 2nd week in November 2013 now.

Answer (score 1):

Just struggled with Visutal Studio 2017 Community Edition - none of above options worked for me.
In my case what i had to do was:

1. Run MySQL Installer and install/upgrade: Connector/NET and MySQL for Visual Studio to current versions (8.0.17 and 1.2.8 at the time)
2. Run Visual Studio Installer > Visual Studio Community 2017 > Modify > Individual components > add .NET Framework Targeting Packs for 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1 and 4.7.2
3. Reopen project and change project target platform to 4.7.2
4. Remove all MySQL-related nuGET packages and references
5. Install following nuGET packages: EntityFramework, MySql.Data.Entity, Mysql.Data.Entities
6. Upgrade following nuGET packages: MySql.Data, BouncyCastle nad Google.Protobuf (for some reason there is an update available just after install)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall later version and install mysql-connector 6.3.9 for visual studio 2010.

After installing add the dll files and restart the visual studio.

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i install mysql for visual studio and the problem simply solved.although version  of my visual studio is 2012!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install to VS 2015 using the Web installer.  It seemed to work, but there was still no MySQL entry for Data Connections.  I ended up going to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/, using it to uninstall then re-install the connector.  Not it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and i have installed mysql-connector-net-8.0.11. But in visual studio is not showing the db connector for mysql. Then I was installed the mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.8 and run the visual studio. Its working fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It works when I right-click the MysqlConnection tab and hit `Re-Run This Query`