# Does Visual Studio 2013 support ADO.NET Entity Model for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ado.net, visual-studio-2013

I've been trying to connect Visual Studio 2013 with a MySQL table using an ADO.NET data entity model but its doesn't give me the option. It only gives me the option to SQL servers. Is creating a MySQL ADO.NET data entity model even possible in VS2013?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879451/mysql-data-source-not-appearing-in-visual-studio may help.

Comment: http://www.bgsoftfactory.net/entity-framework-with-code-first-and-mysql-5-6-14-current-version/

Answer (score 0):

Yes support is there unless if you are using VS express.

For Visual Studio 2013 do the following

Download and install **MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7**. and **Connector/NET 6.7.5, 6.8.3 or 6.9.x.**

Which will resolve your issue.