# Why is the MySQL database not showing in the list of datasources?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET VB 2010. My database is MySQL based. For that I have installed the MySQL version 5.0 and also SQLYOG IDE.
I want to display the data from my database in a listview, so I use the sqldatasource1 but while choosing the datasource, it wont show the MySQL database name in the list. Then I installed net/connector 6.8.3 and added a reference to sql.data.dll. But it doesn't work.

My second question is: what is way to connect MySQL database through the Microsoft ODBC data source?

Comment: you need to install [mysql Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) then you can see `MySQL Database` in  Data source list. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html

Comment: i installed mysql connector.. and your link is for adding the data source....my question is mysql database is not present in the data source list...while select other ...the mysql wont come in list....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879451/mysql-data-source-not-appearing-in-visual-studio

Comment: ok sir... i will check it first then back.....

Comment: now i have installed the net connector 6.5.4.... but it alsodoes not show the  mysql databse

Comment: yeppee.... now it works................wow

Comment: firefly, how did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio available using the MySQL Installer for Windows

[refer](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html)