# MySQL for Visual Studio installation fails, error code 1603

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

The MySQL Datasource is not appearing on my Visual Studio, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774997/3603383) that I need to install `MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7`.

But when I try to install `MySQL for Visual Studio` on my PC (Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 Enterprise), the installation fails at 93% and I get this log :

```
[...]
1: Action 16:30:33: VS2015Setup. 
1: Action 16:30:33: SetVS15Setup_Custom. 
1: Action 16:30:33: SetVS15_Ent_Setup_Custom. 
1: Action 16:30:33: VS15_Ent_Setup_Custom. 
1: 
1: Action 16:30:33: SetVS15_Pro_Setup_Custom. 
1: Action 16:30:33: InstallFinalize. 
1: Action 16:30:34: DeleteRegKeyAndExtensionsFile_VS2012. 
1: Action 16:30:35: DeleteRegKeyAndExtensionsFile_VS2013. 
1: Action 16:30:36: DeleteRegKeyAndExtensionsFile_VS2017. 
1: Action 16:30:36: DeleteRegKeyAndExtensionsFile_VS2017_Pro. 
1: Action 16:30:36: VS14_UpdatePackageFile. 
1: Action 16:30:36: VS2015Setup.
```

Rollback occured after this point

```
1: Action 16:31:16: VS15_Ent_Setup_Custom. 
1: Action 16:31:17: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: VS15_Ent_Setup_Custom
1: VS2015Setup
1: VS14_UpdatePackageFile
1: DeleteRegKeyAndExtensionsFile_VS2017_Pro
1: DeleteRegKeyAndExtensionsFile_VS2017
1: DeleteRegKeyAndExtensionsFile_VS2013
1: DeleteRegKeyAndExtensionsFile_VS2012
1: Action 16:31:17: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: Publishing product information
[...]
1: 1: MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7 2: {63F92630-4546-4297-A0F5-761886A689EE} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7' failed.
```

I've also checked in the MSI logs and I found this :

```
[...]
Calling custom action MySql.VisualStudio.CustomAction!MySql.VisualStudio.CustomAction.CustomActions.UpdateFlagPackagesFileForVs2015
WixQuietExec:  Error 0xffffffff: Command line returned an error.
WixQuietExec:  Error 0xffffffff: QuietExec Failed
WixQuietExec:  Error 0xffffffff: Failed in ExecCommon method
CustomAction VS15_Ent_Setup_Custom returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 16:31:17: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action ended 16:31:19: INSTALL. Return value 3.
[...]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try this link? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/834484/you-receive-an-error-1603-a-fatal-error-occurred-during-installation-e

Comment: Hi, yes I've already tried this link @WojtekT

Comment: Anything in the Windows logs? Looks like maybe you aren't able to update a registry key or possibly an issue around permissions in the registry.

Comment: Nothing in the Windows Event Logs, it just says that the installation failed @JacobH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the issue, so I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 and installed `MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7` on Visual Studio 2015, from now on I am using Visual Studio 2015.