# MySQL is not showing as an option in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am having hard time connecting MySQL to visual studio 2015.The MYSQL is not showing as an option. I tried installing connectors but still nothing.[image]

Comment: possible duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879451/mysql-data-source-not-appearing-in-visual-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Data Source not appearing in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879451/mysql-data-source-not-appearing-in-visual-studio)