# MySql not showing in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I have downloaded Mysql.data , Mysql.data.entityframework , mysqlconnector and additionally downloaded mysql installer.But Mysql not showing in Visual studio 2019.How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you seem to be making an EF6 app; this is quite old now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to install MySql For Visual Studio
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

and net connector
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Have a nice day :)

**Update**

For anyone who has the same problem and my answer is not enough I invite you to read this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879451/mysql-data-source-not-appearing-in-visual-studio), maybe you are in the same situation.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thank you, the problem was solved.

Comment: Good job!!!! :)

Comment: I want to do same thing for Firebird Database.Do you know?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know it :(