# Where is the MySQL Datasource option for Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: mysql, datasource, visual-studio-2022

I am currently working with Visual Studio 2019 and my database is MySQL 8.2.

When I want to connect to my database with Server explorer, in Visual Studio 2019, one of the connection methods listed was MySQL Database. But at the same time when I use Visual Studio 2022, the option is not available. I tried to configure MySQL. But that is of no use as in Visual Studio 2022m the option is not listed. Is there any other method to bring in MySQL?

[image]

Tried ODBC, which works to some extent, but it is not good enough. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Seems at some point Oracle has [deprecated](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/visualstudio/) "MySQL for Visual Studio" and they "encourage" users to switch over to [MySQL Shell for VS Code](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/introducing-mysql-shell-for-vs-code):

> Per Oracle's Lifetime Support policy, as of Dec 8, 2022, MySQL for Visual Studio is covered under Oracle Sustaining Support.
> Users are encouraged to use MySQL Shell for VS Code.

---

**Original Answer**:

Based off of [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879451/mysql-data-source-not-appearing-in-visual-studio), you would normally have to install a separate program called "MySQL for Visual Studio".  The current version of this program is 1.2.10.  However, it seems they do not yet support Visual Studio 2022 according to [this documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20230604165604/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-what-is-new-12.html).  Visual Studio 2019 appears to be the latest version they have support for (since version 1.2.9):

> ### Version Support for Visual Studio
>
> - MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.10:
>
>   - Support for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 was removed.
> - MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9:
>
>   - Support for Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 was added.

They also have a table [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html) showing the supported verisons.

Comment: Sincere thanks, hope they do it soon

Comment: It does not seem to support 2022 yet, so that means there must be another way everyone is doing this via VS2022? It would be nice if I could do it there but using Workbench from time to time is OK.