# MySQL Data Connection for VS 2022 / MySQL for Visual Studio Setup Wizard ended prematurely

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

After quite some time I am coming back to update our database. I'm trying to get MySQL Database to show up in the Visual Studio Add Data Connections dropdown. This has never been very easy but after spending all day on it I fear I cannot continue.

Googling issues with MySQL not being in the Data Connections dropdown shows a lot of answers, I've tried a lot of them but am not even sure which versions of MySQL Server, MySQL .NET Connector, and MySQL for Visual Studio are supposed to be used together for Visual Studio 2022.
I have MySql.Data and MySql.Data.EntityFramework nuget packages installed in my project.

Taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774997/8431320), on my latest attempt, I:

1. Remove all MySQL programs with Revo Uninstaller
2. Run MySQL Community Installer 8.0.34 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

   -Install MySQL Server 8.0.34-X64
3. Install MySQL Connector/NET 8.0.33.1 from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/
4. Install MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.10 from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/visualstudio/

But still no MySQL Database in Add Data Connections.
I fear the MySQL for Visual Studio plugin may be the cause of this, as anything later than 1.2.10 (2.0.2. m1 - 2.0.5 m4) fails with "MySQL for Visual Studio Setup Wizard ended prematurely".

Answer (score 2):

At long last someone here answered the question: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,709633,710100#msg-710100 :

> Sorry, but it's not compatible with 2022. I keep a copy of Visual Studio 2019 around for just this reason.

MySQL for Visual Studio does not support Visual Studio 2022. I switched back to 2019 and it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

According to experience, the following problems usually exist:

**1. Install MySQL Connector/NET**

First, we need to make sure we have installed MySQL Connector/NET correctly. You can go to the MySQL official website to download the latest Connector/NET version, and install it according to the installation guide. Alternatively, you can install using the NuGet package manager.

**2. The MySQL server is not running**

If the MySQL server is not running, you will not be able to connect to MySQL data sources. You can check if the MySQL server is running by following these steps:

Open a command line prompt.

Enter "cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin" (assuming your MySQL server is installed on the C drive).
Type "mysql -h localhost -u root -p" (you will need to enter your password if entered correctly).
If successfully connected, you will see the MySQL window, which means the MySQL server is running.

**3. Firewall blocking MySQL connection**

If your firewall is blocking MySQL connections, you can edit the firewall rules to allow MySQL connections.

Windows Firewall

Open Control Panel and select Windows Firewall.
Click Advanced Settings.
Select Inbound Rules.
Click New Rule.
Select Port and click Next.
Select "TCP" and enter "3306" (MySQL port) in "Specific native port".
Allow the connection.
Enter a name for the rule and click Finish.
other firewalls
If you are using another firewall, you can refer to your firewall documentation to add the ports that allow MySQL connections.

**Summarize：**

Through the above steps, you should be able to successfully connect to the MySQL database and use the MySQL data source in Visual Studio. If you have any other questions or questions, you can go to the official MySQL website for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately there are no Nuget packages with the exact name "MySQL Connector/NET" (I do however have "MySql.Data" and "MySql.Data.EntityFramework" installed). There is also no "MySQL for Visual Studio" extension. Are you sure your answer is up to date for VS 2022?

Comment: @Koops128 Sorry, MySQL Connector/Net has been integrated to mysql.data. MySQL for Visual Studio cannot be found in the expansion market, but you can still download them from Oracle's official website. Regarding the other reasons I mentioned in the answer, have you tried it?