# Connect Crystal Reports in ASP.NET WebForms to MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

I'm trying to change database of existing crystal reports from MSSQL to MYSQL.

I followed [this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774997/148271) and installed MYSQL connector and VS plugin. I'm able to see MySQL provider when I connect from Server Explorer. But I'm still not able to see MySQL provider when I try to connect from Crystal Reports Field Explorer. I already have Visual Studio 2019 and its compatible Crystal Reports and Crystal Reports Runtime.

Versions as follows
MySQL Connector/NET 8.2.0
MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.10
Visual Studio 2019

[image: CrystalReport]

[image: ODBC Data Sources]

Comment: As an alternative, use the data to compose a HTML document and convert it to PDF.

Comment: I have many existing reports