# How to connect Teradata in entity data model wizard

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, teradata

I am trying to add Teradata in vs 2010. Can anyone please help me?

You can check the below post they are trying for mysql. I need for teradata.

[How to connect to a MySQL Data Source in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235291/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing the .NET Data Provider for Teradata found [here](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/dot-net-data-provider). You will have to register for the Teradata Developer Network to download the software if you have not done so previously.

Comment: I have downloaded Teradata 13.11.00.01. Still i dont see any drivers in the entity data model wizard. Please help me