# Mysql datasource for entity framework visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, mysql

No mysql data source for entity frame work for visual studio 2017 enterprise.

[image]

im using visual studio 2017, pls. help.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235291/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to install data connector https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.10.html