# Can't connect to MySQL data source in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mysql-connector

When I try to add a new data source, I can get as far as the final screen where you select your tables before getting this error when I press finish:

[image: You have a usable connection already]

except I don't have a usable connection??? This is a completely fresh C# Windows Forms project with zero code written or anything else done to it.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both MySQL and Visual Studio, no exaggeration, at least ten times. I have tried every single recommendation for permutations of *MySQL for Visual Studio* and *Connector/Net*, including all the ones in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235291/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio) even though they were only meant to work for VS 2010. Not a single one has made any difference and some have even made the problem worse by removing MySQL as an option altogether from the data source list.

I'm absolutely desperate at this point for any help since it seems there has been literally one other person having this problem with VS 2017 and what worked for them isn't working for me.

I am running:

- Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.9.6
- MySQL 8.0.14
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8
- Connector/Net 8.0.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer as I was able to fix the problem by uninstalling the above versions of MySQL for VS and the Connector, and installing instead [MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/) and [Connector/Net 6.9.8](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/) from the linked archives. It still gives a "Specified cast is not valid" error when connecting the data source but it does not seem to impact functioning.