# How to connect to a MySQL Data Source in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, dataprovider

I'm trying to create a new connection using MySql as a Data Provider in Visual Studio 2019, but the list of Data source doesn't show me MySql.
So I check out my mysql-connector and I had the 8.0.15.msi version. I found out that i should have the older version because starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. So i uninstalled my current version and reinstalled this one 6.6.6 but it still dosen't work.

What connector should i Install for visual studio 2019?

[image]

Comment: Where did you read this? Because [the MySQL site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html) has the sentence "This version also removes all features related to Visual Studio Integration, which are provided in a separate product, [MySQL for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/)." Have you installed that separate product? Also see the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939853/215552) to [the question which the same title as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4235291/215552)

Comment: I've installed this separate product for Visual Studio but it still doesn't work, it seems that for Visual Studio 2019 it doesn't work but for older versions it does. I don't know if I'm still missing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem and I solved with this.

First update your components to:

> - Connector/NET 8.0.17
> - MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5
> - MySQL Server 5.5 or higher
> - Entity Framework 6 assemblies
> - .NET Framework 4.0 or higher (.NET Framework 4.5.1 or higher is required for Connector/NET 6.10 and 8.0)

Second review the project packages reference and config files because the NuGet Package Manager don't update it correctly in this Visual Studio version.

This article is in portuguese and You can translate it at Google. It is a step-by-step about Visual Studio 2019 and MySQL integration written by myself: http://sistemaseweb.com.br/Pagina/Detalhes/90/migrando-e-atualizando-um-projeto-net-mvc-3-com-mysql-no-visual-studio

Comment: Is there an updated link for this in 2022? I feel like I've tried every combination of versions.

Comment: To save others time - I just tried this with VS2019 and didn't work for me. Also - broken link. I wasn't using EF, though. Just tried with connector/net version and the mysql for vs version. Got erros. Didn't work.