# Object Relational Mapping (ORM) between MySQL database and c# objects in Visual Studio using LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to establish an ORM between a MySQL database and c# objects in Visual Studio

I have installed  the following packages to add MySQL Database to the data sources list:

- Connector/NET 8.0.16: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

following the recommendations in this post: [How to connect to a MySQL Data Source in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235291/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio)

I have created the data source and my code looks like this ...

Connection string in app.config:

```xml
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyMapper.Properties.Settings.myConnectionString" connectionString="server=my-db-instance.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com;user id=my_user_id;password=my_user_password;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=my_database" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

DataContext in MyDataContext.cs:

```cs
namespace MyMapper
{
   [Database]
   public class MyDataContext : DataContext
   {
      public MyDataContext() : base(Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString) { }
      public Table<ElementId> ElementIds;
   }
}
```

Mapped class in ElementId.cs:

```cs
namespace MyMapper
{
   [Table(Name = "ElementId")]
   public class ElementId
   {
      [Column(Name = "IntegerValue", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
      public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Insert operation in MyController.cs:

```cs
ElementId my_element_id = new ElementId();
my_element_id.IntegerValue(88);

using (MyDataContext my_data_context = new MyDataContext())
{
   my_data_context.ElementIds.InsertOnSubmit(my_element_id);
   my_data_context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

When executing SubmitChanges() the following exception is thrown:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
```

It seems that the problem is the connection with the database

**Update** answering proposed solution in [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci): I am not trying to connect to a SqlConnection but to a MySqlConnection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: Looks like you have used SqlConnection instead of MySqlConnection

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: @SᴇM I was not trying to connect to a SqlConnection but to a MySqlConnection

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya is right, that was causing the exception

Comment: Is this using System.Data.Linq (Linq to SQL)? That framework is Microsoft SQL Server only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data context connection was not a MySqlConnection

```cs
namespace MyMapper
{
   [Database]
   public class MyDataContext : DataContext
   {
      public MyDataContext() : base(new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString)) { }
      public Table<ElementId> ElementIds;
   }
}
```

but now the following exception is thrown:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[ElementId]([IntegerValue])
VALUES (88)' at line 1
```

it looks that the query is not being formatted as MySQL

**UPDATE:**
MySQL support requires NuGet Packages:

- A fully-managed ADO.NET driver for MySQL. The most popular options are:

  - **MySQL.Data**: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ (NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)
  - **SQLite**: https://www.sqlite.org/index.html (NuGet: https:// www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/ or https:// www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/)
- Entity Framework (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)

  - **Entity Framework**: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/
  - **Entity Framework Core**: https:// www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/

I have used MySQL.Data and Entity Framework 6 (EF6): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

The reason to choose EF6 is because EF Core does support Type Per Type (https://entityframework.net/tpt) at the time of writing this answer (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2266)

DataContext in MyDataContext.cs:

```cs
namespace MyMapper
{
   [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
   public class MyDataContext : DbContext
   {
      public DbSet<BaseClass> BaseClass{ get; set; }
      public DbSet<ElementId> ElementId { get; set; }

      public MyDataContext () : base(new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString).ConnectionString) { }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
      {
         dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); // to avoid pluralization of the tables

         // EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
         dbModelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BaseClassConfiguration());
         dbModelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ElementIdConfiguration());

      }
   }
}
```