# MySql DataSource not appear on Visual Studio 2019 Entreprise

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2019, datasource

The MySql DataSource does not appear on list on my VS2019. I have already installed the required plugins: `mysql-connector-net-8.0.22` and `mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.9`, but the issue is not fixed.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235291/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio?

Comment: This should be fixed by installing MySQL Tools for VS and MySQL Connector.  Not via Nuget but using the installer.

Comment: Hi Allen, I have installed those two pluggin from mysql website (dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) but I got the same issue

Comment: @BichriTech, based on my test, I can see the MySQL Database in the Data Source list successfully after I only install the mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.9. Therefore, I have two suggestions about it. First, please ensure your vs2019 is the latest version. Second, please close your vs2019 when you install the mysql for visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, then I downloaded the MySQL for Visual studio and restarted the Visual studio and it worked.